# Creating a data type that holds specific values of another data type

Tags: list, haskell, types, enums, algebraic-data-types

I want to create the following data structure, the first is an algebraic data type OneToTen and the second I want to be a list that holds all the values that OneToTen can be for future mappings I do in my program.

```
data OneToTen = I | II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII | IX | X
???? SetOneToTen = [I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X]
```

Is this somehow possible in haskell, or should i just use a function that returns a list like the one above and work with that?

Update: My haskelly way of doing it:

```
data OneToTen = I | II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII | IX | X
               deriving (Enum, Show)

setOneToTen :: [OneToTen]
setOneToTen = [I .. X]
```

and then just call this function when you want the list :)

Comment: just remove the `????` and rename `SetOneToTen` to `setOneToTen`. Then `setOneToTen` is a list of `OneToTen`s.

Answer (score 4):

just remove the `????` and rename `SetOneToTen` to `setOneToTen`:

```
data OneToTen = I | II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII | IX | X

setOneToTen = [I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X]
```

Now `setOneToTen` is a list of `OneToTen`s.

If the data type contains only data constructors with no parameters, you can easily make these an instance of `Bounded` and `Enum`, in that case you can use `[minBound ..]` to construct the list of possible values:

```
data OneToTen = I | II | III | IV | V | VI | VII | VIII | IX | X deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum)

setOneToTen = [minBound ..]
```

Comment: Thanks that should work just fine , I guess a normal list it is then :)